# min pair of consecutive numbers of array

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I need the minimun adjacent pair of a given array with **dynamic programming.** 
Why isnt working?

```
def prepare(array):
    list = []
    for i in range(len(array)-1):
        lista.append(sum(array[i:i+2]))
    return sum(array) - psu(list)

def psu(array):
    if len(array) < 2:
        return array[0]
    first = array[0]
    array.pop(0)
    return min(first,psu(array))

def min(left,right):
    if left > right:
        return right
    return left
```

Comment: By dynamic programming? How should your algorithm work?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.  "Isnt working" is not a problem specification.